# PostgreSQL selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looks like:

```
user  key
x     1
x     2
y     1
z     1
```

The question is simple. How to find out which one is the user who has not key 2?
The result should be y and z users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jarlh's answer is likely the fastest if you have ***two*** tables;
- One with the users
- One with your facts

```
select "users"."user_id"
from "users"
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                   where t2."user_id" = "users"."user_id"
                     and t2."key" = 2)
```

That's the structure I would recommend too, having two tables.

For your case, where you only have one table, the following may be a faster alternative; it does not need to join or run a correlated sub-query, but rather scans the whole table just once.

```
SELECT
    "user"
FROM
    tablename
GROUP BY
    "user"
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN "key" = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: jarlh's answer doesn't use two tables. It only uses a single table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : that was my point, I don't agree that jarlh's answer is the fastest in the case of having just one table with a degenerate user dimension.

Comment: You second query lacks `= 0` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Return a user row as long as the same user doesn't have another row with key 2.

```
select user, key
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.user = t1.user
                    and t2.key = 2)
```

Note that `user` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit it as `"user"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
SELECT "user", "key"
FROM Your_Table AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Your_Table AS T2 ON T1."user" = T2."user" AND T2."key" = 2
WHERE T2."user" IS NULL
```